# Cross-reference schema.org ‘Person’ data

Tags: html, relationship, microdata, schema.org

I have a page mentioning several people. Most of them are connected to eachother in some way. For the purpose of this question lets say I have 3 people: John Doe, Jane Doe, and their child Baby Doe:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="john">
    <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="jane">
    <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="baby">
    <span itemprop="name">Baby Doe</span>
</div>
```

This [parses without any problems](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/?html=%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22john%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJohn%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22jane%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJane%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22baby%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EBaby%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E) (using Live Microdata).

Now I would like to cross-reference these people with eachother. Jane is John’s wife. So I will need a `spouse` property to match. Of course the opposite is true also: John is Jane’s husband.

Baby has both John and Jane as its parents. Ergo both John and Jane should have baby as their child.

How do I set this up? Whatever I have tried with `itemref` has been unsuccessful.

For instance, I can make Baby the child of both John and Jane but Baby will no longer be its own entity on the page: ([see parse](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/?html=%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22john%22%20itemref%3D%22baby%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJohn%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22jane%22%20itemref%3D%22baby%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJane%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20itemprop%3D%22children%22%20itemscope%20itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%20id%3D%22baby%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EBaby%20Doe%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E))

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="john" itemref="baby">
    <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="jane" itemref="baby">
    <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="children" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="baby">
    <span itemprop="name">Baby Doe</span>
</div>
```

Is there anyway for me to keep all persons as seperate entities and still cross-reference them as eachothers spouses, siblings, parents, children, etc? There is no one central person on the page to use as main `itemscope`.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you can't do this with schema.org. What you're talking about is "relationships" (e.g. ["marriage" in Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/people/marriage?schema=)). But schema.org doesn't provide this kind of abstraction.